# Primefaces multiple select checkbox bean values in Javascript function

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces multiple select table populated from a backing bean. I am using the table.getSelectedRowsCount() javascript widget var to validate atleast one selection and it is working fine.

I now want to throw up a javascript confirmation dialog based on the state of the selected rows. for ex I have a button at the bottom of the table for printing the details of selected rows. I need to check a certain field of the bean and then allow printing.

IN pseudo code

```
if (#{bean.isComplete})
   allowPrinting();

else
   // alert user that this row is not yet in complete state
```

Answer (score 0):

Update and panelGroup on button ajax event as shown in follow.

```
<h:panelGroup id="validateRerpot">
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.isComplete}">
<script type="text/javascript">alert('show Dialog inplace');</script>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Try to update validateReport panel